# Activate menu item if url param changes

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-router

I have a sidenav that has a dropdown included. In it you could choose a user. Depending on the user, different menu items are available (no problem). If you change the user via dropdown (no matter on which menu item you are), you should be forwarded to the user details page (also working).

Now to the problem: If I am on the detail view for userA (menu item is highlighted) and I change the user to userB, I (correctly) will stay on the details view. The url changes correctly and the view will show details for userB. BUT the menu item isn't highlighted anymore. I tried out a lot, but nothing works so far.

Sidenode: I'd like to change navigation within a service, as I like to add more logic and need to use it in other components as well.

What I have right now (pretty much shortened):

- sidenav.component.html

```html
    <mat-list-item>
      <div>
        <mat-label fxLayout="row">
          <span>Selected User</span>
        </mat-label>
        <mat-select #select placeholder="Select User" (selectionChange)="selectionChange()">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let u of user" [value]="u">
            {{ u.name }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </div>
    </mat-list-item>

    <mat-list-item>  
      <a mat-line [routerLink]="['/user', user.id, 'details']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">User</a>  
    </mat-list-item>

    // more mat-list-items in here
```

- sidenav.component.ts

```js
    selectionChange(): void {
      this.userService.navigate();
    }
```

- user.service.ts

```js
    navigate(): void {
      this.router.navigate(['/user/' + this.user.id + '/details']);
    }
```

- app-routing.module.ts

```js
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: MyAppComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'user',
            loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule',
          },
          {
            path: 'user/:userID/details',
            loadChildren: './user-details/user-details.module#UserDetailsModule',
          },
        ],
      }
    ];
```

Does anyone have an idea how to keep menu item activated, if only the parameter in the url changes? I'm using Angular6.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: For clarification the sidenav in the end looks like this:
User Dropdown (with UserA and UserB)
Details
Projects
[More Menu Items]

I want to have `Details` highlighted when I'm on this view

Comment: Your component which displays detail view should subscribe to ActivatedRoute. You obtain the userId and set what user you're actually viewing details for, all you have to do is set the userId in the service, and your sidenav component should get the user id from the service. https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

Comment: you mean like this?  in detail view `this.subscriptions.push(this.route.paramMap.subscribe((m) => { this.userID = m.get('userID'); }));`

Comment: in sidenav I already get the user from the service.

Comment: Can you show your code that makes "menu item highlighted" ?

Comment: Only used `[routerLinkActive]="['active']"` on the `a`tag in the sidenav.html so far and style it via css `a.active {background-color: #FF0000}`
Unfortunately the `active` class get's lost when calling `router.navigate()` on the same url with different userID parameter. Seems like I'm doing something wrong :/

Comment: active is a css property triggered when the link is clicked so I would say the behavior is pretty normal. I can suggest you : `<mat-option *ngFor="let u of user" [value]="u" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': u.id === userId ? '#FF0000' : 'none' }">`

Comment: create a userId variable in your sidenav component and assign the id of your `user` variable in your user.service

Comment: With your ngStyle suggestion I only style my dropdown, right? But I want to style the selected menu item, sorry if this was unclear. I have a dropdown with all users and outside of the dropdown I have different menu items like `Details`, `Projects`, `...` When I'm on e.g. the Projects page and I call the Details page via `router.navigate()` the menu item `Detail` gets highlighted. If I'm already on `Details` the highlighing disappears. :/

Comment: Create a sidenav service in which you create a BehaviorSubject that holds the current "menu" you are navigating. In your sidenav template you check your behaviorsubject's value and add the css-class accordingly. If you don't know how to do it, create a small stackblitz i'll be glad to help

Comment: Silly me! I already use behavioursubject's for the selected user, thank you for remembering me to also use it for the menu items :+1: works!